# How to export individual slides as PNG with files names from instructor notes

Tags: vba, export, powerpoint

I've just started trying to code VBA to run a macro that will automatically save the contents of every slide as a PNG (1796px x 1010px).

I have managed to find a piece of code that will do this - many thanks to the author.

Now I need to edit this code, so that the macro will copy the text from the first line of the instructor notes and use this as the file name for the PNG.

Ideally the pictures will be saved in the same directory as the PPT file is located in.

Any ideas???

This is my current code:

```
Sub Export_Media()

Dim sld As Slide                ' defines "sld" as currently displayed slide
Dim shp As Shape                ' defines "shp" as a shape object
Dim shapeName As Object         ' defines "shapeName" as an object

    i = 1                       ' defines "i" starting at 1

' This section loops through each slide that is not hidden and saves it as a PNG 1796 x 1010
For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each shp In sld.Shapes
    On Error Resume Next
        If ActivePresentation.Slides(i).SlideShowTransition.Hidden = msoFalse And shapeName(ActivePresentation.Slides(i), "NameofShapeonSlide") Then
            ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Export filenamepng & "SlideName" & i & ".png", "PNG", 1796, 1010

        End If
    i = i + 1
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You're off to a good start, but use the documentation and experiment. Use the watch tool  and debug. There's a property within the slide that you should be able to find this. type a period and it will autopopulate with all options. There's also lots of documentation on Microsoft that breaks down each of these objects. Your answer is in the slide object.

Comment: ActivePresentation.Path & "\" will give you the path to your presentation.
sld.NotesPage.Shapes("Notes Placeholder 2").TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs(1) will give you the first line of the notes page text unless somebody's "improved" the notes page.

Comment: Hey, thanks for all your help, Im pretty new at this so I appreciate it :)

Comment: Ive amended the code to include the suggested parts: ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Export ActivePresentation.Path & "\" & sld.NotesPage.Shapes("Notes Placeholder 2").TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs(1) & ".png", "PNG", 1796, 1010.   Now the macro seems to be adding a "?" at the end of the file names and is overwriting some of the files :(

Comment: Look at the first line of the notes text. If it ends in a ? then, that's what your code will try to use for the exported PNG. You'll need to replace that with "". Likewise, if there's more than one notes page with the same first line text, the last one in will win and the previous ones will be overwritten.

Comment: There is no ? symbol in any of the notes on any of the slides.  Also all the text in the first line of each notes section of each slide is different, so I can't figure out what is going on :(

Comment: Suggestion:  edit your original question so that it reflects the current version of your code.